# How to make Listview items views view Visible onLongPress

Tags: android, listview

I have 1 ImageView , 1 textview and 1 seekbar in listview items. Seekbar by default visiility is GONE. Now i want to set visibility of seekbar as per database value. If database value is YES then it will display seekbar on long press and if its No then it will do nothing on long press. Currently if i long press on any item it is showing seekbar.

**ApplianceAdapter**

```
public class ApplianceAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
public ApplianceAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c, 0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.appliancelist, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView txtApplianceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtApplianceName);
    final LinearLayout btnApp = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btnApp);
    final SeekBar slider = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.slider);

    String appliance = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("AppName"));
    String dimmer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Dimmer"));

    txtApplianceName.setText(appliance);
    if (dimmer.contains("YES")){
        btnApp.setLongClickable(true);
    }else if (dimmer.contains("NO")){
        btnApp.setLongClickable(false);
    }

}
}
```

**Appliance Activity**

```
public class Appliance extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> applianceList;
DBOpenHelper db;
String room;
String type;
Cursor appliance;
ApplianceAdapter applianceAdapter;
SeekBar slider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_appliance);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String r = intent.getStringExtra("roomname");
    room = r.replace("{name=", "").replace("}","");

    db = new DBOpenHelper(this);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listAppliance);
    appliance = db.getAppliance(room);
    applianceAdapter = new ApplianceAdapter(this, appliance);
    listView.setAdapter(applianceAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
     {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            slider = listView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.slider);
            slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return false;
        }
    });


}


}
```

Comment: You need to notify adapter. Add this line 'applianceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();' after slider visible in long press.

Comment: what do you want? is this code works fine? And do you want to implement it with db result?

Comment: still it is visible for No value. @SulabhGajjar

Comment: No @JyotiJK. Basically i am showing Appliance List from database. Which contains appliance name and Appliance have dimmer or not? If appliance have dimmer then i have to show seekbar on long press and if no then it will remain GONE. By default Seekbar is GONE in every list item.

Comment: Do you want to display seekbar for all long clicked items or only the last item which is long clicked. @Acg

Comment: last item only.. but it has to be YES value in dimmer variable check in Adapter class.

Comment: @Acg from where you have declare your slide view? I mean in xml. Is it in activity xml or in list view row xml?

Comment: it is in row. But @JyotiJK helped me with answer below. So it is solved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            youradapter.lastclicked=position;
            youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And in your adapter,

```
if (dimmer.contains("YES") && cursor.getPosition()==lastclicked){//initially lastclicked = -1
    slider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else if (dimmer.contains("NO")){
    slider.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: btw view.getPosition is invalid method. I used cursor.getPosition and it works fine